# Как обработать значения списка, используя Coroutines Flow?

Tags: android, kotlin

Есть вот такой метод:

```
private suspend fun getPhotoFileList(photoUrlList: List<String>): List<ByteArray?> {
        return photoUrlList.map { downloadCarPhotoUseCase(it).first() }
    }
```

use case выглядит вот так:

```
interface DownloadCarPhotoUseCase {
    suspend operator fun invoke(fileName: String): Flow<ByteArray>
}
```

`List<String>` конвертируется в `List<ByteArray>`. Можно ли переписать данный метод, на реализацию как было в Rx? С помощью flatmap можно было обработать все значения списка и с помощью toList() собрать их в один список и вернуть назад? Как это сделать во Flow?

Comment: а зачем? чем текущее решение не устраивает?

Comment: От этого зависит логика приложения. Так в двух словах не объяснить. Нужно по каждому значению списка - отправить запрос в сеть, с обработкой ошибки (если что то пошло не так) и в collect  получить List< ByteArray>. И прописать уже логику в collect.

Comment: те вам нужно возвращать `Flow<File>`?

Comment: Ошибочка вышка. Нужно возвращать ByteArray. Поправил

Comment: ByteArray или Flow<ByteArray> или List<ByteArray>? Из вашего вопроса ничего не понятно. Понятно только, что хотите как в RX, только опять не понятно, что значит как в Rx, не вижу примера на Rx

Comment: Мне нужно пройти по списку строк. По каждому значению строки отправить запрос в сеть и получить в ответ ByteArray. Метод который делает запрос в сеть по значению строки возвращает Flow<ByteArray> . Мне нужно собрать все ответы в кучу и отдать List<ByteArray>. Все запросы в разных потоках.